# textarea height and width in jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I fixed the the height for text-area element in jQuery mobile and i got perfect height and width in portrait but in landscape the width doesn't enlarge. can any one help me? thanks in advance.

```
HTML:        <textarea cols="55" rows="50" name="textarea" id="newMarkCompleteCommentText" style="background-color:White;width:95%;height: 50px;"></textarea>

IN JS:
    $('#newCommentText').attr('style', 'background-color:White;font-size:18px;height:7em;');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting "width: auto". Also, instead of ".attr('style', ...)" you can use ".css('attribute', 'value')"

```
$('#newCommentText').css('background-color', 'white').css('font-size', '18px').css('height', '7em').css('width', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the width and height, you don't need to set cols and rows. Try removing those values and the textarea should expand with your % values.

Also, is your textareas containing element set to expand?

Comment: Actually, the css width and height always override the rows and cols. Still don't need to set rows or cols if you're setting css width and height, but this doesn't answer their question at all. Should have posted this as a comment.