# asp:Textbox controls autoresizing to 2 rows with jquery mobile

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, textbox

I have the following control on a jquery mobile page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ContactUsMessageTextBox" TextMode="multiline" Columns="30" Rows="7" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am finding that for some reason when the page is loaded the textbox will start out with one row then enlarge to contain 2 rows. It doesn't appear to matter how many rows I have specified, as this is always the case (even if specifying one or two rows.

I have also tried to alter the number of rows on page load to no avail.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ContactUsMessageTextBox.Rows = 7;
        }
    }
```

Altering the body height also does not make a difference. Does Jquery Mobile handle asp textboxes differently? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/19119922/1771795

Comment: That fixed the issue! Want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :) I can't add a duplicate answer ;)